# EROFS is read-only error message in Ubuntu snap VSCode when using Apc Customize UI++ extension

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, snap

I'm current trying to use the [Apc Customize UI++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drcika.apc-extension) extension on VS Code. Using on Windows It worked perfectly, but on Ubuntu i faced this error:

> Apc Extension failed: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, rename '/snap/code/151/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js' -> '/snap/code/151/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/bootstrap-amd.js.apc.extension.backup'

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Could someone save me?

Sorry about bad english, it's not my primary language...

I've tried to Google it so far, but found no response. Looks like nobody uses this extension on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that the extension is trying to make changes to some file inside the VSCode package. VSCode is installed using `snap` on your system, and snap packages are immutable, so such a change can not be made.

The easiest way to solve it is to install VSCode using a deb package. To do this, follow the instructions on this page: [Running Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions) (specifically, "Debian and Ubuntu based distributions" section).

Alternatively, you can just [download .tar.gz distribution](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-x64) of VSCode, this kind of package doesn't require installation and would work if you unpack it and launch `code` executable. The benefit of this is that all the files would be owned by the user that unpacks the package, meaning that this extension shouldn't have any problems modifying such VSCode installation if the executable is launched by the same user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but running this command resolved it

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/share/code
```

This is a [link](https://github.com/drcika/apc-extension/issues/131#issuecomment-1902589109) to the github issue

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the awnser. But unfortunately it didn't work. On my Ubuntu the path /usr/share/code does not exist. I tried changing the path `/snap/code` and `snap/code/151/usr/share/code/resources/app/out` too, but neither solved my problem.